# proof or disproof if $ L_1 \subseteq L_2 $ then $ L_1 \leq L_2 $

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

proof or disproof

if $ L_1 \subseteq L_2 $ then $ L_1 \leq L_2 $

I tried to think with HP and the empty language because HP is in RE and the empty language is in R but how do I prove this does not always happen? I don't understand whats the formal way to write it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim essentially says that if $L_1$ is included in $L_2$, then $L_2$ is harder than $L_1$, which clearly cannot be correct as the biggest language w.r.t containment is very simple. So you can take $L_1$ to be the halting-problem, and $L_2$ to be $\Sigma^*$. Proceed from there.

Comment: but then the claim works , i want to disproof it,

Comment: HP is reduciable to $ \Sigma^*$

Comment: There is no way that $HP \leq_m \Sigma^*$ because $\Sigma^*$ is in $\text{R}$ and $HP$ is not. The intuition is that if $L_1 \leq_m L_2$, then $L_2$ is harder to decide that $L_1$. Formally, $L_2\in R \to L_1 \in R$.

Comment: @mayacohen I think you got the definitions mixed-up. Another way to see that there is no reduction $f: \Sigma^*\to \Sigma^*$ from $HP$ to $\Sigma^*$ is by noting that for all $x\notin HP$, we have that $f(x) \in \Sigma^*$.